# Accessing application property in Spring boot application from MapStruct mapper

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mapstruct

I want to access `basic-info.expiration` from `application.yml` a Spring boot application.

##### application.yml

```yaml
basic-info:
  expiration: 6
```

##### UserMapper.java

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface UserMapper {

  @Value("${basic-info.expiration}")
  static long expireInMonths = 0;
  // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  @Mapping(target = "requireBasicInfoUpdate", source = "user", qualifiedByName = "isBasicInfoUpdateRequired")
  UserDto toUserDto(User user);

  @Named("isBasicInfoUpdateRequired")
  default Boolean isBasicInfoUpdateRequired(User user) {
    final var expireDate = LocalDate.now().minusMonths(expireInMonths);
    final var lastUpdatedOn = user.getBasicInfoUpdatedDate().toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();

    return expireDate.isAfter(lastUpdatedOn);
  }
}
```

How to inject property value with MapStruct

Comment: You cannot because it is an interface and an interface cannot have fields only constants. You might shoehorn this into an `AbstractClass` (also supported by MapStruct) and make i work. But you really should reconsider adding this in the mapping and rather make it part of the user instead (your mapper should map, not include business logic which now it kind of does).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @M. Deinum suggested, interface was changed to an abstract class. This is the most preferred method since application need no refactoring.

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public abstract class UserMapper {
  @Value("${basic-info.expiration}")
  long expireInMonths = 0;

  @Mapping(target = "requireBasicInfoUpdate", source = "user", qualifiedByName = "isBasicInfoUpdateRequired")
  public abstract UserDto toUserDto(User user);

  @Named("isBasicInfoUpdateRequired")
  public Boolean isBasicInfoUpdateRequired(User user) {
    final var expireDate = LocalDate.now().minusMonths(expireInMonths);
    final var lastUpdatedOn = user.getBasicInfoUpdatedDate().toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();

    return expireDate.isAfter(lastUpdatedOn);
  }
}
```